# Why is my pandas multi_index groupby and agg not working under 1.0.3?

Tags: python, pandas

Under pandas 0.24.2, I've been able to do large multi-index groupby and agg statements. Now that I unpgraded to 1.0.3, I'm getting a `MemoryError: Unable to allocate 5.74 EiB for an array with shape (3309234388567429969,) and data type int16`.

What's the change and why doesn't this work with the new version?

Here is how I'm grouping:

```
train_sample_tab = train_sample.groupby(['policy','Written Premium','Number of Families','Age of Home'
                                         ,'Age of Insured','Dwelling Limit (01)','latitude','longitude'
                                        ,'Insurance Score'], as_index = False).agg({'Description':'count'}).reset_index()
```

Here are the dtypes:

```
policy                  float32
Written Premium         float32
Number of Families      float32
Age of Home             float32
Age of Insured          float32
Dwelling Limit (01)     float32
latitude                float32
longitude               float32
Insurance Score        category
```

Comment: What is your code? How do your data look like? You are trying to allocate `5.74 EiB` of memory.

Comment: question edited.

Comment: @QuangHoang.  The original shape is `(1273,38)`

Comment: Also, I reinstalled 0.24.2 and it worked so I'm not sure what changed and which version it actually changed.